# Customisation of UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I want to customise a [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html). The user will be asked to select a

- **year** (1984-2100) and
- **quarter** (Q1-Q4).

An exact input of the date (with options day/month/year) is unfortunately not an option. An acceptable compromise would be only showing options for month and year.

- As far as I have researched, it is not possible to customise Apple's
  UIDatePicker in that way. Am I right?
- Which other options would I
  have to solve that problem?
- Are there any 3rd party options that
  solve this specific issue?

I am aware of the [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPickerView), but I hoped I could avoid hacking two pickers together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help? It of course is built on top of UIPickerView, as there really is no way of modifying the UIDatePicker to hide days.

https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHMonthYearPickerView

You also could customize it very easily by changing the month numbering and names in the `LTHMonthYearPickerView.m` file.

Comment: that answer is more awesome that I thought it would be: The customisation of the LTHMonthYearPickerView was really easy; I will document my code, clean it up and upload it to a second github branch. Thank you so much, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you can't use `UIDatePicker`. Use a `UIPickerView` with two components, one for the year and one for the quarter.